# Is there an SEO difference at targeting a keyword with a Wordpress page versus a post?

Tags: seo, keywords, ranking, page, post

My questions are, what is best practice for targeting long tail keyword phrase with pages or posts.

1. Text content WordPress page optimized for keyword phrase, linked to homepage, category page or post.
2. Post internally linked to anchor keyword page/post.

Is there a distinct difference in how search engines treat these?

Comment: You say "linked to" but I think you mean "linked from".   If you are creating a new page, it is far more important for SEO to figure out where it should be linked *from* rather than to worry about where the links on that page will point.

Comment: Hello Stephen,Thanks for reply. concept, was to create cornerstone pages linked from relevant page.closely related keyword sub pages cornerstone page. some o keywords doesn't look readable e.g "extreme ripped jeans"  Creating the 1st " cornerstone page and including the most closely related keyword phrases may not b interesting on a blog but may be an essential part of a site's page architecture.Can keyword pages linked from page, post, or product category assist the visibility of the page, post, or product category or is this a redundant methodology.Regards, John

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, yes, there is a slight difference in SEO based on whether you create a Page or a Post.

It has to do with how Google interprets the content. If you create a Post, it will automatically appear in things like Categories and Date Archives, and themes often display the updated date. These signal to Google that this is a timely article - best suited to queries that are time-dependent. For example, if you are talking about an annual event and writing details that are specific to the current year, a Post is a good way to go because it signals this is specific to the current month/year.

Similarly, if you are talking about that annual event but want to keep a single page which you update every year, a Page would be the way to go because it is seen as more static content. You could still add Schema event markup (in this example) to signal to Google that there is timely content, but over time you would build up more links to this one URL than you would to a Post.

Finally, there may be differences depending on what kind of theme you use. Many themes use an `<article>` tag around Posts but not around Pages. So the actual HTML that is rendered may vary somewhat and could be a little better optimized in either a Page or a Post, but this varies so much by theme you'd have to dig around and determine this for the theme you are using.

Overall there are not many differences, so as in almost all SEO questions, do what makes sense for your human visitors and the spiders will fare better as well.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful reply Elaine, Understand most of what you say about pages vs post content.

Answer (score 1):

It’s more important than ever to have content that plays by the following rules:

- Contains at least one image
- Has optimized images with alt tags and relevant titles and descriptions
- Loads fast
- Covers the topic in-depth, offering plenty of new and helpful information
- Has a keyword density of 1% or less
- Links to 3 to 5 high-authority, relevant sources
- Has internal links to relevant content

Following these steps can help you rank your content. But, you also need to use your long tail keywords properly within your content so that you have a better chance to rank.

First, be sure to use your main keyword in your SEO title, preferably toward the beginning, in your introductory paragraph and in at least one heading within your content. Then, you can sprinkle your secondary keywords throughout your content. It’s also a good idea to use one of your keywords in your meta description.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sara,Have most of that covered.Couple of questions.Where do you take the reference for keyword density from?3-5 outbound links, what rules do you apply to this?Many thanks.John

Comment: keyword density is not a number for the count and I meant to use the keyword at least in your content to introduce the concept of the page, both to user and search engine. but I tried so many ways for backlinks and I have got a good result from this much backlink for promoting

Comment: Hi Sara, thanks for your reply.I was reading up on this and the clearest guidelines seem to come from Hobo web; https://www.hobo-web.co.uk/keyword-density-seo-myth/ and in the quotes from Dr. Edel Garcia. (one of the few information retrieval SCIENTISTS whose crossed over into seo)..interesting reading.